# still Failed to create chart: can't acquire context from the given item

Tags: vue.js, chart.js, vue-composition-api

can't seem to make this work even after seeing the previous post

here is the vue template

```html
<template>
<div>
   <canvas id="acquisitions" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
  </div>

</template>
<script src="../pages/taara/script/acquisitions"></script>
```

and here is the script

```js
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
import Chart from 'chart.js/auto'
export default defineComponent({
  name: 'BarCharts',
  setup() {
    ;(async function () {
      const data = [
        { year: 2010, count: 10 },
        { year: 2011, count: 20 },
        { year: 2012, count: 15 },
        { year: 2013, count: 25 },
        { year: 2014, count: 22 },
        { year: 2015, count: 30 },
        { year: 2016, count: 28 }
      ]

      new Chart(document.getElementById('acquisitions'), {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
          labels: data.map((row) => row.year),
          datasets: [
            {
              label: 'Acquisitions by year',
              data: data.map((row) => row.count)
            }
          ]
        }
      })
    })()
  }
})
```

i see this in the documentation, after the given error

```
   Failed to create chart: can't acquire context from the given item
```

i found some posts with the same issue and after applying the answer
still not working.
please see the work, appreciate your help. and im new to vue and chart.js

Answer (score 2):

In plain English, the error is telling you the chart can't find the `<canvas />` DOM element when `new Chart()` is run.

That's because the `<template />` contents are not available when `setup()` is run. They only become available after the component has been mounted (a.k.a: added to DOM), so you should place the creation of the chart inside `onMounted`, imported from `vue`.

As a side note, you shouldn't use `document.getElementById` at all, it's recommended you use [template refs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html).

Last, but not least, you don't need the async iife inside setup. I'm quite certain you can safely remove it.

In other words, this should do it:

```js
import { defineComponent, ref, onMounted } from 'vue'
import Chart from 'chart.js/auto'

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'BarCharts',
  setup() {
    const data = [
      { year: 2010, count: 10 },
      { year: 2011, count: 20 },
      { year: 2012, count: 15 },
      { year: 2013, count: 25 },
      { year: 2014, count: 22 },
      { year: 2015, count: 30 },
      { year: 2016, count: 28 }
    ]
    const canvasRef = ref(null)
    onMounted(() => {
      new Chart(canvasRef.value, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
          labels: data.map((row) => row.year),
          datasets: [
            {
              label: 'Acquisitions by year',
              data: data.map((row) => row.count)
            }
          ]
        }
      })
    })
    return { canvasRef }
  }
})
```

And place the `ref` on the `<canvas />`:

```html
  <canvas ref="canvasRef" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: hello bro, can you provide the code to fast my development and i will try to understand how it works. i'm a slow learner bro. very much thankful for your help.

Comment: any way bro thanks very much for the hint. i will do my best.

Comment: bro your so good i get it. God bless you bro

Comment: @MikaelTenshio, updated the answer with returning the `ref` from `setup()`. Otherwise, it won't be available in `<template />`. This is required by `defineComponent({})` syntax, and not required when using `<script setup>` syntax (which I typically use).

Comment: help me again bro. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75830557/cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-months